# PostgreSQL get minimum of count(*)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to get the minimum count of data. my current sql is

```
select min(count(*)) from table group by id ;
```

where i expect to get minimum count of variable count(*). Seems like above query is not allowed. Error

```
aggregate function calls cannot be nested
```

is thrown. Is there a way achieve this using any alternating method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many solutions exist as attested by the number of answers here.
Interestingly, @ahorse_with_no_name questions the performance of each of them.

#### The subquery approach

```
SELECT MIN(count) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY id) t;
```

It typically yields the following plan:

```
Aggregate
   ->  HashAggregate
         ->  Seq Scan on table
```

#### The ORDER/LIMIT approach

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY id ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1;
```

It feels more natural to some but unfortunately yields a second sort:

```
 Limit
   ->  Sort
         Sort Key: (count(*))
         ->  HashAggregate
              ->  Seq Scan on table
```

#### The CTE approach

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY id) SELECT MIN(count) FROM cte;
```

It is very similar to the subquery, except that the plan shows the CTE is scanned (and could be materialized if the table is large).

```
 Aggregate
   CTE cte
     ->  HashAggregate
           ->  Seq Scan on table
   ->  CTE Scan on cte
```

#### The window aggregate function approach

Alternatively, you could use a window aggregate function combined with LIMIT and just avoid the second sort.

```
SELECT MIN(COUNT(*)) OVER () FROM table GROUP BY id LIMIT 1;
```

It yields a plan equivalent to the subquery approach (if we consider `LIMIT 1` as nearly free).

```
 Limit
   ->  WindowAgg
         ->  HashAggregate
               ->  Seq Scan on table
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap that in a sub-select:

```
select min(cnt)
from (
  select id, count(*) as cnt
  from the_table
  group by id
) t
;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this without a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from table t
group by id
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

I actually wanted to find a solution using `distinct on` (Postgres specific).  The following does the trick as well:

```
select distinct on (case when id = id then null end) count(*)
from table t
group by id
order by (case when id = id then null end) , count(*) desc;
```

The weird `case` expression is because `()` is not allowed with `distinct on`.  And, you can't use a constant in an `order by`.  The `case` expression is a trick to allow *something* that isn't really used but is needed to only get one row.

Comment: It seems that he wants minimum, not maximum. Or maybe I misinterpret something.

Comment: I was curious if your `limit` version or my sub-select would perform better. On my computer performance is basically identical, but the execution plan for the `limit` version seems to be a bit more expensive: http://explain.depesz.com/s/AW1 and http://explain.depesz.com/s/tHL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . The difference doesn't surprise me.  It is not the `limit`, but the `order by`.  In general, an aggregation would be more expensive, but the processing can be simplified to a single pass when there is no `group by`.  In any case, I prefer the `limit` because you can pull other information out of the row (such as the id with the maximum count).

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
select count(*)  count from table group by id 
)
select min(count) from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select count(speed)
from pc
where speed = (select min(speed) from pc)
```

Comment: I think you mean `id` (and not `speed`). I also think you may have misunderstood the question. The query needs to return the number of rows containing a given `id` where that `id` appears the least number of times. Your query returns the number of rows containing the smallest `id` value. Nevertheless, incorrect answers are considered valid answers on SO. Also, I suggest that you learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your posts. By the way, have you taken the [tour]?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**